# Передать объект из JS в PHP (AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте умные люди, подскажите пожалуйста с решением такой задачи.
Есть у меня такой ассоциативный массив, например

```
{andromeda: ["Ламинат Tarkett Universe Андромеда", "2.5", "10", 1447, "1 510,01"]
tsentavr: ["Ламинат Tarkett Universe Центавр", "2.5", "10", 1447, "1 510,01"]}
```

.
Нужно предать его через AJAX в php-файл

```
$.ajax({
        url: "api.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "order": cart,
        }
```

PHP:
if

```
(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !isset($_POST['order'])){
$order = '';
foreach($_POST['order'] as $row){
$order .= '<tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">' . $row[0] . '<br />' . $row[1] . '</td>'.'<td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">' . $row[2] .'</td><td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">' . $row[3] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Как нужно сконвертировать объект, или обратчик изменить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сделать проще. Есть метод в JavaScript [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), а в PHP есть [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php). Вы можете передать объект (ассоциативный массив) обычной строкой и распарсить ее в php.

В PHP удобный синтаксис в этом смысле:

```
$object = json_decode($_POST['stringfy_json'], true); 

//true - для получения ассоциативного массива
```

Comment: Проблема была в данных которые я отправлял в php-скрипт, я перебрал объект в массив и всё вышло